# ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: vb6, call

The codes I write just is some part of my whole codes as I just want to test whether for the part sub procedure can be run or not. When I run, a message come say :By Ref argument mismatch.  I am not familiar with using call to call the sub procedure. Anyone please help me !

```
Dim Age As Integer
Dim Weight, Heights, BMI, BMR As Single
Dim MenBMR, WomenBMR As Single

Private Sub cmdBMI_Click()
If Age > 20 Then
Call AdultBMI(BMI)
End
End Sub

Private Sub AdultBMI(BMI As Single, Weights As Single, Heights As Single)
Age = Val(txtAge.Text)
Weight = Val(txtWeight.Text)
Heights = Val(txtHeight.Text)
BMI = Weight / ((Heights / 100) ^ 2)

If BMI < 18.5 Then
txtBMIValue.Text = BMI
txtBMIStatus.Text = "Underweight"
MsgBox ("You are underweight!")
End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

`BMI` is a variant.

In this line below

```
Dim Weight, Heights, BMI, BMR As Single
```

`Weight`, `Heights` and `BMI` are all variants. In VB6 you have to explicitly provide the type of each variable when you use commas. Try this.

```
Dim Weight As Single, Heights As Single, BMI As Single, BMR As Single
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there are a number of problems with this code and I'll put out as many as I can see.

You've made BMI, Weights and Heights parameters to the sub-routine AdultBMIbut you're using them as local variables inside the sub-routine.  Parameters are used to bring values in from outside the sub-routine.  See below for how I would change your code.

When you've called AdultBMI you've only given it one parameter instead of the three the routine expects and this is why you're getting an error.

You have an End statement just before your End Sub.  End will terminate your program immediately.  You need to use 'End If'

Ideally your AdultBMI sub-routine would be a function that took two parameters Weight and Height and then returned the BMI:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim BMI As Double
    BMI = AdultBMI(Val(txtHeight.Text), Val(txtWeight.Text))
    If BMI < 18.5 Then
        MsgBox "Underweight"
    End If
End Sub
Private Function AdultBMI(ByVal Height As Double, ByVal Weight As Double) As Double
    AdultBMI = Weight / ((Height / 100) ^ 2)
End Function
```

I think you need to understand a little more about variables and scope as it will serve you well as you progress with programming.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function named
`AdultBMI()` which takes three arguments as seen in your function definition.

You are calling this function using only one argument. Where are the rest two?

You have the definition which is

```
Private Sub AdultBMI(BMI As Single, Weights As Single, Heights As Single)
    Age = Val(txtAge.Text)
    Weight = Val(txtWeight.Text)
    Heights = Val(txtHeight.Text)
    BMI = Weight / ((Heights / 100) ^ 2)

    If BMI < 18.5 Then
    txtBMIValue.Text = BMI
    txtBMIStatus.Text = "Underweight"
    MsgBox ("You are underweight!")
End
End Sub
```

here you are expecting three arguments as `Private Sub AdultBMI(BMI As Single, Weights As Single, Heights As Single)` but in your function call, you have passed only one argument `AdultBMI(BMI)` It should be like `AdultBMI(BMI,Weight,Height)`. and anyways you have used `global variables` and you are passing `global variables` within function calls which is not necessary. They are available throughout your program. You have not even initialized your variables but you are checking them under conditions. You must first initialize them via some `textbox` or an`inputbox` etc.

Also, you have a `variant` data which you are passing to a function which is expecting a `single` data.
You need to declare each variable individually as `dim a as single, b as single` and not as `dim a,b as single`. this will make `a` as a variant

Anyways, if you want your code to stop showing the argument mismatch error, then try out this code

```
Dim Age As Integer
Dim Weight As Single, Heights As Single, BMI As Single, BMR As Single
Dim MenBMR As Single, WomenBMR As Single

Private Sub cmdBMI_Click()
    If Age > 20 Then
    Call AdultBMI()
End Sub

Private Sub AdultBMI()
    Age = Val(txtAge.Text)
    Weight = Val(txtWeight.Text)
    Heights = Val(txtHeight.Text)
    BMI = Weight / ((Heights / 100) ^ 2)

    If BMI < 18.5 Then
        txtBMIValue.Text = BMI
        txtBMIStatus.Text = "Underweight"
        MsgBox ("You are underweight!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helping, because i am new to visual basic ^^

Comment: @shirley By looking at your code, it seems you are trying to learn all at once. Learn step by step.